# how to return a formatted number by String.format in English?

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, non-english

When I using `String.format` method, if my phone language be Farsi this method return the formatted number in Farsi language. but I want to use an English formatted number.
I using this code:

```
String.format("%.02f", myNumber)
```

my question in picture:

[image]

Comment: Can you just change the locale? Or am I missing something here? 
        String strValue = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%.02f", myNumber);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to use the [`String.format(Locale, String, ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method with an English Locale instance, probably with `Locale.ENGLISH`.  This will tell String.format to use English number formatting instead of Farsi.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Should be OK.  The "zero digit" (0 for English, ۰ for Persian) is buried deep in the Locale.

Comment: It's not working for me. I am using a Custom textView with a different font to display the formatted String.  Is that make any issue?